# When does onPauseAnimation for AnimationListener get called?

Tags: android, android-animation

When does onPauseAnimation for AnimationListener get called? How can we use onPauseAmimation to use any other animation to perform and resume previous animation?

'

```
animator.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
                Log.e("Testing : ", "onStart");
                super.onAnimationStart(animation);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                Log.e("Testing : ", "OnStop");

                super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationPause(Animator animation) {
                Log.e("Testing : ", "OnPause" + "it will never get called..");
                super.onAnimationPause(animation);
            }
        });
        animator.start();
```

'

Comment: Where is your code? Where do you call [pause()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/Animator.html#pause())?

Comment: Your code does not contain any call to `animator.pause()`. Where are you expecting it to pause?